# Adobe InDesign Query

Tags: windows, adobe-indesign

I purposely went to InDesign to make a cover photo for our company Facebook page. I made sure to check the size required and found that Facebook cover photos are 851 x 315 pixels. Now that I have a document filled with photos at 851 x 351, Windows tells me I cannot save as a JPEG because the document is too large.

How can I export to .jpeg in InDesign?

Comment: It sounds like there isn't enough space on the hard drive you're saving it to - not a graphic design problem

Comment: Make sure that your document is also in pixels, not in kilometers.

Comment: InDesign is a poor app for this any way. If you're set on Adobe, use Illustrator. If not, give [Sketch](http://bit.ly/MacSketchApp) a try.

Comment: Perhaps Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Using InDesign for creating covers is a little bit overkill in my opinion. It's complicated and messy for such simple tasks and you're much better off going with something simpler. Microsoft Publisher is ideal although if you're a Mac user its not available but there are plenty of alternatives to [Publisher for Mac](https://machow2.com/publisher-for-mac/). Hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a valid reason to install another software as InDesign is a great tool for digital publishing.

I have tried to save a .jpg document with both of your dimensions 851x351 and 851x315, and did not notice any issues in InDesign. Make sure you have the latest version of InDesign installed and you use File->Export->JPEG->Export command.

[image: Export JPEG InDesign]

It sounds that it is a problem on the side of your PC not InDesign in this case. You can check couple of things:

- You have enough free space on your drive (as suggested in comments) and there are no bad blocks and SMART status is healthy (run diagnostics on your drive).
- The dimensions are set correctly, in your case it should be 70p11x26p3 (as suggested in comments).
- You are running up-to-date version of InDesign.
- You are running up-to-date version of Windows.
- You have enough RAM.
- You can try closing all other currently open resource consuming software so that InDesign will be the only software running at that moment.

There can be more suggestions on what you can do, based on your responses to the mentioned above steps.

Answer (score -1):

Try saving it as a .pdf then from there in acrobat exporting it as a JPEG or a Reduced Sized PDF if that doesn't work. Rinse and Repeat until it works!

Comment: How does repeating the process help?

Comment: There's a potential his computer cannot save too large of a JPEG, so if he keeps systematically reducing the size of the PDF he might get to a size the computer will allow him to export a JPEG at. Purely speculation!

Comment: Too large JPEG at less than a 1000x1000 pixels?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using Lucidpress instead. It's kind of like a [publisher for mac](https://www.lucidpress.com/pages/tour/microsoft-publisher-for-mac) tool. Illustrator mentioned above is great too, but it's not free.